# Attach a runnable to UI thread without using Handler

Tags: android, concurrency, android-asynctask

I will come out straight that this is a assignment question .So I am not looking for a answer but a better answer .

We have a Async Task which takes in three parameters . The progress parameter(i.e 2nd parameter is) is a Runnable .

```js
@Override
    public void onProgressUpdate(Runnable ...runnableCommands) {
        // TODO -- you fill in here with the appropriate call to
        // the runnableCommands that will cause the progress
        // update to be displayed in the UI thread.
    }
```

I am able to make calls to this method using publishProgress() in doInBackGround() method.

The challenge is to have this runnable attached to UI Thread. I know that onProgressUpdate() has access to UI thread and we can create a handler to add to message queue . But apparently it is excessive.

Can some guide me to a better way to do this than create a handler

Comment: I never tried it but please try runOnUiThread(Runnable action). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316838/is-using-runonuithread-inside-asynctask-inefficient-and-bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a reference an Activity, an easy way is using the [runOnUiThread(Runnable runnable)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)) method.  Looking at the source code, it's really easy to see why:

```
public final void runOnUiThread(Runnable action) {
    if (Thread.currentThread() != mUiThread) {
        mHandler.post(action);
    } else {
        action.run();
    }
}
```

If you have a reference only to a View, you can use the [post(Runnable runnable)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post(java.lang.Runnable)) method.

The JavaDoc for both states the Runnable will be executed on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation

**onProgressUpdate**

> This method can be invoked from doInBackground(Params...) to publish updates on the UI thread while the background computation is still running.

You can find a link here [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate(Progress...))

Basically this method already runs on the UI thread. So you dont need any further code (via handelrs or runOnUiThread()).

In your case, you can just directly call `run` of that Runnable.